# Delphi 10.4 Setup SFTP Client with PPK

Tags: ssh, sftp, delphi-10.4.2

I am searching for a possibility to load up a simple text file to an SFTP directory. I was shocked as I noticed a nearly 5k worth development environment is not able to connect to an SFTP Server (20-Year-old standard specification), without taking another 500 bugs to buy a Component from a third-party developer Studio. Am I right? Or is there a way to get an SFTP connection with Delphi Board Components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find a solution with Delphi components.
I used "SFTP Client and Server Library" from /n Software.
Works like expected, Support is good.